# why *ptr is not working while using float array, did I mistake with the wrong format specifier or something else?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, integer

In this code i was trying to print the array using pointer but it just doesn't work with float array. Note: i have done this exact same code with int array and it was working fine and as expected but this on the other hand is miserable. Float array is the problem i guess.

CODE:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    

    float arr[]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 54};
    int *ptr ;
    ptr = arr;


    printf("%u\n", ptr);
    printf("%u\n", *ptr);
    printf("%d", &ptr);

}
```

i am expecting this output.

OUTPUT:
address of arr[0]      .
value of arr[0]         .
address of ptr

Comment: "did I mistake with the wrong format specifier or something else?" --> Enable all compiler warnings to quickly see the trouble.  Faster than posting on Stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with you use a pointer to an `int` to point to your array. That needs to be `float *` to be correct:

```
float *ptr = arr;
```

Then lets take the `printf` statements one by one...

We start with:

```
printf("%u\n", ptr);
```

Here `ptr` is a pointer. The format `%u` is to print an `unsigned int` value. To print a pointer you need to use the `%p` format. And the pointer need to be a `void *` pointer. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Second:

```
printf("%u\n", *ptr);
```

Once you fix the pointer issue mentioned first, then you use `*ptr` which is the same as `ptr[0]` which is a single `float` value. The recommended format to print a `float` (or a `double`) value is `%g` or `%lg`. Again you have mismatching format specifier and argument type.

Lastly:

```
printf("%d", &ptr);
```

Here `&ptr` is a pointer to the variable `ptr` itself. It will have the type `float **`. As before you have mismatching format specifier and argument type.

To solve your problems you need to use correct specifier and arguments:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) ptr);
printf("%g\n", *ptr);  // ptr[0] would also work
printf("%p", (void *) &ptr);
```

Most compilers available today should be able to detect these kind of problems and issue warnings about them. You might need to enable more warning to get the warnings. Always treat warnings as errors that must be fixed.

Comment: Re “`ptr[0]` which is a single `float` value”: No, it is not. Look at the definition of `ptr`.

Comment: This is still not working, the garbage value is still there

Comment: @RudraVyas: “the garbage value is still there”: What “garbage” value? You never showed any output. When asking for help with a program, show the exact text of the observed output, as well as a sample of the output you expect.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    float arr[]= {1, 2, 3.4, 4, 54};
    float *ptr ;
    ptr = arr;
    printf("%p\n", ptr);
    printf("%g\n", ptr[2]);  
    printf("%p", &ptr);
}
this worked, thanks everyone for helping

Comment: That is the source code, not the output. And you didn't address the issues raised by @Someprogrammerdude either.

Comment: @RudraVyas Curious, this answer used a `(void *)` cast in `printf("%p\n", (void *) ptr);`, yet per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74841928/why-ptr-is-not-working-while-using-float-array-did-i-mistake-with-the-wrong-fo#comment132081222_74841957), you did not.  Why did you  code `printf("%p\n", ptr);` (not quite correct) and not the suggested (and correct) `printf("%p\n", (void *) ptr);`?

Answer (score 2):

`int *ptr ;` tells the compiler that `ptr` is a pointer to an `int`. Then `ptr = arr;` attempts to assign a pointer to a `float` to this pointer to an `int`.

The compiler prints a warning or error message when you do that. Do not ignore warnings from your compiler. Enable warnings in your compiler and elevate warnings to errors.  With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.

Change `int *ptr ;` to `float *ptr;`.

`printf("%u\n", ptr);` is not a correct way to print a pointer. Use `%p` and convert the pointer to `void *`: `printf("%p\n", (void *) ptr);`. Do the same for `&ptr`: `printf("%p\n", (void *) &ptr);`. Also, do not leave `\n` off when printing; always print a new-line character at the end of the line. (This is useful both for buffering issues and for making the end of your program’s output clear, not mingled with your command-line shell prompt.)

`printf("%u\n", *ptr);` is not an correct way to print a `float`. After changing `ptr` to `float *`, use `printf("%g\n", *ptr);`.